# Travesring up in jQuery until an element with a selector is found

Tags: jquery

I need a way to traverse up in jQuery until a specific element is found, even it's outside the parent of the element that I am currently on.

```
<ul>
 <li class='c1'>
  <span class='need'>data</span>
 </li>
 <li class='c2'>
  <span class='here'>data2</span>
 </li>
 <li class='c3'></li>
</ul>
```

Let's assume that I am in 'here'. I want to traverse up the tree until I find 'need'. I can't use `.closest()` because it doesn't traverse outside the parent element that I'm in. I need it to search up in all the outer elements including the children, until it finds the first instance that satisfies the selector.I need only the first instance of the element found.

In the above example, I need a code that returns the first instance of the element `.need`.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: So, in example given you need to find the very root `ul`, right? `$('.here').closest(':has(.need)')`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko it can be inside a parent higher up, not the first . I'm checking your code now..

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I don't need the root, but the element that is inside the root that contains what I need. In my site it translates to: $(this).closest( ":has([data-level='0'])" );, but I need the element that has data-level=0, not his parent. I think it might be requires a recursive function, because there is a need to search the children of the parent elements first as you travel up the tree, and stop until the element with the selector is found and return it.

Comment: Couldn't you do `.closest().find()`?

Comment: It won't be good because the closest selector will match the first parent, return null if the .need is not in the first instance that the .closests stops in. IF you do it this way, you need to run closest().find() on each parent element and see which one returns an element that satisfied the condition (.need exists in it)

Comment: `$('.here').closest(':has(.need)').find('.need').eq(0)`?

Comment: Alternatively, could you add a class to the shared root element and perform `.find()` on that?

Comment: I think that your last suggestion works. Doing a few more tests.

Comment: It works! thanks so much. Please submit this answer '$('.here').closest(':has(.need)').find('.need').eq(0)'. Works perfectly. I will add a class to make it simpler in my cose.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
$('.here').closest(':has(.need)').find('.need').eq(0)
```

Credits: [Travesring up in jQuery until an element with a selector is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419590/travesring-up-in-jquery-until-an-element-with-a-selector-is-found#comment64246367_38419590)